# Dependency Injection Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, inversion-of-control, unity-container, ioc-container

I am not sure how to use Dependency Injection on Xamarin Android project solution. Currently my Android solution holds a reference to another class library solution. I have used Unity on my service layer and registered the container via WebApiConfig.cs.
My question is, how do i go about using Unity on Android side in order to run on start up, would be grateful if code was included. I dont want to new-up the container through main activity of Android. I want the container to register behind the process i.e. AppStart or Global asax where it does it for you for MVC apps. Is there a way to do it for Android? Also I noticed on Main Activity I am unable to create constructor. I guess this isnt possible but how do I go about holding object reference to my Class Library solution ? example that i attempted to do:

```
private IExample _ex;

MainActivity(IExample ex){
_ex = ex; //depedency Injection rather than newing it up 
}

public void DoSomething(){
 _ex.HelloWorld(); 
}
```

Is there a way to do it via Attribute ? Also for each of my layer do I need to install and create container in order to resolve current solution dependency ? or can I use container from android which would resolve all dependency in each layer as DDD architecture goes from outer to inner ?

Answer (score 0):

In terms of setting up DI at startup you can create a custom Application implementation like so:

```
// Must include this attribute so that Android knows we want to use this as our Application implementation
[Application(Icon = "@drawable/Icon", Label = "@string/ApplicationName")]
public class MyApplication : Application
{
    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();

        // Do your DI initialization/registration here
    }
}
```

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by not being able to create a constructor on the main activity. You can create constructors for any activity you feel like. You don't always see it though because people tend to put their initialization logic in OnCreate.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the prompt message. Once I created the custom Application with its implementation, does the custom application run at runtime without having to initialize from another class or from Main Activity?

Comment: The only thing you have to do is tell Android that you want to use your class as your custom Application implementation. You can either specify that manually in the AndroidManifest.xml file or use the [Application...] attribute to have the compiler do it for you. Once you do that, the operating system will automatically call the OnCreate method at startup without you having to explicitly call it; you can then do "application-wide" initialization like DI setup/registration.